# How can I make steps/tasks from WorkflowTemplate show up in Argo workflows UI?

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, argo-workflows

[image: should be three dot but I only see one]
Why does the workflow just end on an arrow pointing down?

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: WorkflowTemplate
metadata:
  name: workflow-template-whalesay-template
spec:
  templates:
  - name: whalesay-template
    inputs:
      parameters:
      - name: message
    container:
      image: docker/whalesay
      command: [cowsay]
```

This is the worflowtemplate I'm using. I applied this to k8s before the next step.

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Workflow
metadata:
  name: workflow-template-dag-diamond
  generateName: workflow-template-dag-diamond-
spec:
  entrypoint: diamond
  templates:
  - name: diamond
    dag:
      tasks:
      - name: A
        templateRef:
          name: workflow-template-whalesay-template
          template: whalesay-template
        arguments:
          parameters:
          - name: message
            value: A
```

This workflow references the previous step. Workflow is doing what its suppose to do but I can't see the green dots on the UI.

Comment: My guess is something went wrong running the first step. What version of Argo Workflows are you using? What kind of cluster are you using (docker-desktop, Minikube, GKE, etc.)? Can you add the exact steps you've used to install the WorkflowTemplate and submit the Workflow?

Comment: Just wrote this up for ya :-). https://dev.to/crenshaw_dev/how-to-debug-an-argo-workflow-31ng